# Preprocessors in C

Tags: c

I have a doubt in the output of a code. The code uses preprocessors of c language. The code is given below,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define sqr(x) x*x

int main() {

    int x = 16/sqr(4);
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

The result of sqr(4) is equal to 16. So, the value in x must be 1 (16/16=1). But if I print the value of x, the output is 16. Please explain me why this is happening.

I am attaching the screenshot of output pane.
[Output Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkUme.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, macros are filled into your code upon compilation. Let's consider what happens in your case:

Your macro is:

```c
#define sqr(x) x*x
```

When it gets filled into this:

```c
int x = 16/sqr(4);
```

You would get:

```c
int x = 16/4*4;
```

Operator precedence being equal for `/` and `*`, this gets evaluated as `(16/4)*4 = 16`, that is, from left to right.

However, if your macro were this:

```c
#define sqr(x) (x*x)
```

then you would get:

```c
int x = 16/(4*4);
```

... and that reduces to `1`.

However, when the argument for your macro is more complex than a simple number, e.g. `2+3`, it would still go wrong. A better macro is:

```c
#define sqr(x) ((x)*(x))
```

Comment: But would give an unexpected result in `sqr(2 + 3)`.

Comment: Well spotted. I've added your observation.

Comment: I just missed the expansion of macro concept while solving that code. So, I just asked such a silly question. Thank you everyone for answering.

Answer (score 1):

After macro replaces your expression, it becomes int x = 16/4*4 and is evaluated accordingly. i.e. (16/4)*4 which is 16.

sqr(x) doesn't calculate 4*4, it is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually doing 16/4*4 which is in fact 16.

You can change your define to

```
#define sqr(x) (x*x)
```

Now you will be doing 16/(4*4).

Answer (score 0):

It is expanded to

```cpp
int x = 16/4*4;
```

Something like

```cpp
#define sqr(x) ((x) * (x))
```

would be more safe, precedence and associativity-wise, still works poorly in expressions like `sqr(a++)`. Inline functions are simpler to use in this context.